# Gunicorn not running can't connect to sock file

Tags: django, gunicorn

I've got a gunicorn script that fails to load.

Here's it's code

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/revamp
ExecStart=/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the response from status

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-19 14:17:56 UTC; 2min 1s ago
  Process: 26564 ExecStart=/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=1/FAI
 Main PID: 26564 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 19 14:17:51 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:51 +0000] [26564] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Jul 19 14:17:51 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:51 +0000] [26564] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jul 19 14:17:52 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:52 +0000] [26564] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jul 19 14:17:53 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:53 +0000] [26564] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jul 19 14:17:54 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:54 +0000] [26564] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jul 19 14:17:55 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:55 +0000] [26564] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jul 19 14:17:56 samuel-pc gunicorn[26564]: [2017-07-19 14:17:56 +0000] [26564] [ERROR] Can't connect to /home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock
Jul 19 14:17:56 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 19 14:17:56 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 19 14:17:56 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

the sock file isn't created in the folder, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 16):

Looks like the user that you are using to run gunicorn as a service (sammy) does not have permission to access the project folder.

You can check the folder permission with `ls -l`

To change them you can do:

```
sudo chown sammy:sammy /home/sammy/revamp
```